# share og:image is not working but shows at the debugger

Tags: facebook, image, share

i have these lines in my code:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title of the page" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="he_IL" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain.org.il/pagefriendlyname" />

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domain.org.il/upload/image.JPG" />
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.domain.org.il/upload/image.JPG" />

<meta property="og:site_name" content="websitename" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxx" />
```

this is the final version i'm with. before i didn't have app_id of old image_src tag, but in all that time on the debugger i see the image, but when i share the page it just ignore the image.

Answer (score 1):

Since http://www.domain.org.il/upload/image.JPG is an invalid image url, I would presume that your image size or aspect ratio is out of standards for Facebook.  Ensure your image is in compliance with both.